# Changes from windows to MAC OS / WAMP to MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wamp, mamp

In WAMP(Windows) my code was as below. After getting a MAC, while using MAMP what changes should I make to make my code work ?

Current MAC settings :

Apache : 8888
Mysql :   8889

{

```
define('DB_NAME','form2');   //This is my database name 
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
```

}

Comment: That code would run exactly the same on any version of php. it's just defining some constants. We have no idea how your Mac is setup...

Comment: @MarcB 
I have edited my post, what should be my constants now ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to change any structure of your code. It's working PHPcode. But you may have to assign new values to your constants if they have changed on your new system.

Comment: Currently in MAMP my ports are:

Comment: Apache : 8888
Mysql : 8889